# User error: Reset failed (STM32373 ARM4)

Tags: c, arm, stm32, iar

I am using STM32737 MCU and IAR ide.

I have built my own pcb for STM32737 to interface with analog circuit, and Bluetooth module.

I am programming using SMD in [st-link v2](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM146/CL1984/SC724/SS1677/PF251168?sc=internet/evalboard/product/251168.jsp)

When I try to download my program into the mcu, it prompt me an error:

> User error: Reset failed

I have tried on 3 pcb, 2 failed and 1 download success.

The fail download reason is the "Reset failed" error message.

May I know what would be the possible cause for the above failure?

[image: reset failed]

[image: stm32]

**Info Update**

[image: stlink]

Comment: This is very hardware-specific, and you're not providing enough detail (I think). Are you programming using JTAG, or SWD? What software is generating the error on your host machine? Did you check that software's documentation? Also, of course, perhaps your PCB has faults.

Comment: SWD with st link v2.

Comment: I haven't worked with stm32, but I have often gotten cryptic error messages from IAR, when I have tried to reprogram code protected ARM chip. I have had to do manually erase, before I have been able to continue.

Comment: how to do manual erase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the stupid problem: schematic design fault.

There is an unwanted component blocking the reset voltage. Remove the component and device is ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you hold the RST pin at VCC directly with a wire or low resistance pull up it will keep the debugger from being able to reset the uC.